# node.js Error Cannot find module 'optimist'

Tags: meteor

I had upgraded the node to v0.6.18
Then I started using the meteor.
Whenever I use any command related to meteor I got an error.

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:596:18
    at Object. (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:632:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)

In order to solve this issue I used 'npm install optimist'.
It has installed successfully. But it didn't solve my problem.
Please suggest some solution to this issue.

Comment: You know I had a similar problem -- but with a different module that couldn't be found.  I didn't ever find the cause, but I fixed it by just rebuilding my meteor project: copying all my sources minus the contents of .meteor to a new directory, and re-adding all my meteor packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using meteorite with meteor.

This page has a rather straightforward guide as to how to add NPM packages.